# Is there any reason to touch collectables many times?

Tags: idlelands

I'm new to [Idlelands](https://play.idle.land/).  I'm currently going around "touching" various "collectables".  I don't really know why: all it seems to do is increment a counter.

[image]

**Question**: Is there any reason to touch collectables many times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Touching collectibles increases your 'Touchy' achievement, which gives a percentage bonus to XP gained as well as a title at tier 5 (100.000 Touches)

As far as i know that is the only effect of touching collectibles multiple times per ascension.